# How to use merge functionality in data flow azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I know we can use Joins but i am having issues let me explains.

If i have a CSV file which have some data and there is row which have these values

**ID:3 ,Name:Sam ,Role 2**

Now the Data Source have the same data but name has been change from Sam to Man

**ID:3 ,Name:man ,Role 2**

In SSIS we use Merge which update the record.As i am learning Data Flow I have no idea What to use here

CSV-->Join-- Sink ?

Answer (score 1):

In ADF Data Flows, Join will be the most natural transformation to use here.

Kamil Nowinski put together a nice cheat sheet for ADF-to-SSIS data flow translations: https://sqlplayer.net/2018/12/azure-data-factory-v2-and-its-available-components-in-data-flows/